# non www to www domain?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I've changed my conf file so that when a user types in the domain without www it redirects to the domain with www:

server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
I also wish for my https for anything under /user

I get the error of too may redirects, where am I going wrong?

So I have:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/example.com/site;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}
location /user {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
}
}
```

For port 443:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;

root /var/www/example.com/site;
index index.html index.htm;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate //path here
ssl_certificate_key //path here

location / {
        rewrite ^ http://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
}
location /user {
}
}
```

Comment: Where are your other two `server` blocks?

Comment: Michael Hampton - im not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to have separate `server` blocks for `example.com` and `www.example.com`. The entry for `example.com` should *only* have:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

The entry for `www.example.com` will have everything else (and obviously *not* have the redirect).

Similarly, you will have two separate server entries for https (port 443).

Comment: Thanks but could I possibly have a complete example? It's not clear how I would restrict https for /user only?

Comment: The config you have looks correct for that. You just need to split example.com and www.example.com into separate sections and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: (untested)

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  example.com;
return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  www.example.com;
       root /var/www/example.com/site;
       index index.html index.htm;

location / {
       rewrite ^/index.php;
          }
}
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name www.example.com;
   root /var/www/example.com/site;
   index index.html index.htm;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate //path here
   ssl_certificate_key //path here


  location /user {
                  rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
                 }
 }
```